# Сравнение ассоциативных массивов php

Tags: php, массивы, php7

нужно сравнить несколько ассоциативных массивов, которые относятся к друг другу, как `1:м`. Все реквизиты в массивах разбиты на группы с сходными именами например `a1`, `a2`, a3`,`a4` и т.д.
Например: есть массивы основной вида

```
array(
    'a1' =>1,
    'a2' =>2,
    'a3' =>3,
    'b1' =>1,
    'b2' =>2,
    'b3' =>3
);
```

Ну и соответственно дополнительный массив

```
array(
   '0' => array(
                'c1' => 2,
                'c2' => 1,
                'd1' => 1,
                'd2' => 2,  
         ),
  '1' => array(
               'c1' => 3,
               'c2' => 4,
               'd1' => 4,
               'd2' => 5,   
   )
);
```

Как видно из примера, основной массив один, дополнительных несколько.

Реквизиты в основном и дополнительных массивах в сравниваемых группах называются по разному. Заранее известно какие реквизиты должны совпасть в основном массиве и дополнительных.

Так вот, нужно проверить все ли значения основного массива соответствуют значениям в дополнительных.

Судя из примера сравниваем группу реквизитов в основном группу реквизитов `А`,  в дополнительных группу реквизитов `C`

```
[a1] = [0][c2], 
[a2] = [0][c1],
[a2] = [1][c1].
```

УСПЕХ все значения основного массива были найдены в дополнительных массивах.

Чего не скажешь группе `b` и группе `d` дополнительного

```
[b1] = [0][d1],
[b2] = [0][d1], [d2]
```

– в дополнительных массивах, соответственно это ошибка. Так вот, как лучше это сделать, никак придумаю, как это лучше сравнить, и получить ответы что не сошлось. Заранее благодарен за ваши дельные мысли))

Забыл важный момент, дополнительных массивов может быть 1, а может быть очень много (50 и более). И что должно быть, если например в Группе `А` имеется 3 **различных** значения, и они все были найдены в значениях реквизитов соответствующей группы (в данном случае `С`) дополнительных массивов, то все хорошо, да же если в дополнительных массивах соответствующей группы **различных** значений гораздо больше чем 3. Но если были найдены не все. то ошибка.

Comment: "Заранее известно какие реквизиты должны совпасть в основном массиве и дополнительных." - где это указано в коде? Или все значения реквизитов, указанных в основном массиве,  должны совпадать с хотя бы одним значением из дополнительного массива?

Comment: @16artemiy16 ну вот пишет, что `A` сравниваем с `С` а `b` с `d`, вот это и есть видимо заранее известные условия сравнения.

Comment: @АлексейСемянников а вот так   `'a1' =>1, 'a2' =>1, 'a3' =>1,` Успех?  или значения из второго массива надо один раз использовать?

Comment: @teran "Судя из примера сравниваем A с C". По какому критерию мы должны определять что с чем сравнивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кхм, пусть будет третий вариант ответа с diff, раз уже написал код.

исходные массивы

```
$src = [ 'a1' =>1, 'a2' =>2, 'a3' =>3, 'b1' =>1, 'b2' =>2, 'b3' =>3 ];

$check = [
            ['c1' => 2, 'c2' => 1, 'd1' => 1, 'd2' => 2,],
            ['c1' => 3, 'c2' => 4, 'd1' => 4, 'd2' => 5,]
        ];
```

сравниваемые категории

```
$srcCat = 'a';
$checkCat = 'c';
```

фильтруем исходный по нужным категориям

```
$src_filter = array_filter($src, function($k) use ($srcCat){
                        return mb_strpos($k, $srcCat) === 0;
                    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

и результат тоже фильтруем

```
$check_filter = [];
array_walk_recursive($check, function($v, $k) use (&$check_filter, $checkCat){
    if(mb_strpos($k, $checkCat) === 0) $check_filter[] = $v;
});
```

сравниваем результаты

```
$diff = array_diff($src_filter, $check_filter);
```

если `$diff` не пуст, то видимо это не успешное завершение вашего алгоритма.

```
print_r($diff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно сравнить элементы первого массива с элементами всех остальных массивов, и получить в результат массив элементов из первого массива, которых не оказалось во втором - для этого можно использовать `array_diff()` в комбинации с `array_map()`:

```
$arr_1 = array(
    'a1' =>1,
    'a2' =>2,
    'a3' =>3,
    'b1' =>1,
    'b2' =>2,
    'b3' =>3
);

$arr_2 = array(
    '0' => array(
        'c1'=> 2,
        'c2'=> 1,
        'd1'=> 1,
        'd2'=> 2,
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'c1'=> 3,
        'c2'=> 4,
        'd1'=> 4,
        'd2'=> 5,
    )
);


$result = array_map(function($a)use($arr_1){
    return array_diff($arr_1, $a);
}, $arr_2);

var_dump($result);
```

В результате будет двумерный массив, состоящий из элементов первого массива, которые не найдены во втором:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a3' => int 3
      'b3' => int 3
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'a1' => int 1
      'a2' => int 2
      'b1' => int 1
      'b2' => int 2
```